# SELECT INTO with EF4

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

I'm new to c#, linq, and EF4, so please bear with me. I'm sure it's something really simple, but not seeing it.

The stored procedure I'm replacing does a SELECT INTO to query a bunch of data, do some simple transformations, and then output the results into another table. Then, this set of data is returned for local processing in the code.

I have a query that pulls my data into an anonymous type and handles all of the transformations. But, how do I go about sending that data up into the results table?

Initially, I thought of using the entity type to store my initial results. But I have extra fields that I need for local processing that will not be stored in the result table.

Thanks to any EF masters who care to take a crack at this for me!

edit: Here's some pseudo code based on Morteza's help, but doesn't seem to move the data --

```
var ctx = new ReportEntities();
var query = from s in ctx.Source
            select new
            {
                s.SourceID,
                s.OtherStuff
            };

query.ToList().Select(q => new Report()
{
    SourceID = q.SourceID,
    OtherStuff = q.OtherStuff
});

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of EF4 you can update your model with your individual stored procedures and import them as functions. I think the easiest way would be to take advantage of this new feature and create a second procedure that accepts the result data as parameters and save them into the result table. So you can call this function once you done with your data processing.

**Update:**

```
var ctx = new ReportEntities();
var query = (from s in ctx.Source select new {
        s.SourceID,
        s.OtherStuff}).ToList();

List<Report> reports = query.Select(q => new Report() 
{
    SourceID = q.SourceID,
    OtherStuff = q.OtherStuff
}).ToList();

// Now you need to add your new report objects to the Context:
foreach(report in reports) {
    ctx.Reports.AddObject(report);
}

// Now is the time to call the SaveChanges on ObjectContext:
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I thought about that, and it would be easy enough. Thing is... I'm trying to learn to do things the "new" way. As such, I'm backing away from stored procedures and trying to keep it in the code. Am I off base on trying to do it this way?

Comment: Well, since you said "it pulls my data into an anonymous type", I gathered that you probably do not have an EntityObject mapped to that result table, but if you do, then you can certainly populate it with the results and persist it into DB without using an stored procedure. Do you have such an entity in your model?

Comment: Yep, I am projecting into an anonymous type because I'm returning extra fields not in my result table. I need the extra fields for some local processing later on in the code. And yes, the result table is in my EDM.

Comment: Perfect, so you can start by creating a new Object of your result entity and then use AddObject() method followed by a Context.SaveChanges() to insert it into DB. Let me know if you need help for doing so.

Comment: Great. I was thinking along these lines. But where I'm unsure is moving the data between the anonymous type and the entity object. Do I need to manually loop the anonymous type data and create/set a new entity object for each record? Or, is there an easier way to move/translate it? I have 500-1000 records at a time on average.

Comment: Yes you have to iterate through your anonymous objects collection and create an EntityObject for each. However, you don't necessarily have to do it with a foreach loop. You can leverage LINQ's Select method like this: collection.Select(c => new myEntityObject(){...}).ToList().

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I think I'm close, things compile and have proper intellisense, but I get the error "The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query." when using linq's select method as you specified. In your example, "collection" is the IQueryable object from my main query, right?

Comment: No, collection was the IEnumerable of your objects. By having IQueryable, your Select will be executing on the DB instead of in memory. Please post your code and I will fix it for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now you've got me feeling like a real noob! ;-) I fixed it so I am working with an IEnumerable, and that worked. But, unfortunately, the data doesn't seem to be moved. The only thing I can think of is that the Report object I'm creating may not be wired into the context? I posted the code.

Comment: Dude, I think you did pretty good so far. Thanks for posting the code, it looks really good and you just need to call AddObject() before calling SaveChanges(), like I said before :) I edited my answer with updating your code, please check it out.

Comment: Seems so simple now. You rock! Thanks a bunch!